# how to replace leftBarButtonItem by backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

In Interface Builder I created a view as part of a Storyboard which used to be only shown in one different context (as the view of a UITabBarController).

Now I want to reuse this view as part of a UINavigationController view however, which generally works fine. The only problem is that in IB, I placed a button to be the leftBarButtonItem. So when I push that same view Controller on the navigation controller's stack it won't automatically place the backBarButtonItem anymore.

Is there a standard approach on how to deal with that situation? Do I have to remove the button myself, depending on whether the viewcontroller is part of a UITabBarController or UINavigationController? I would like to keep the button in IB. So setting leftBarButtonItem to nil on viewDidDisappear for instance only kind of helps. That does show the backBarButtonItem correctly but when the user goes back to that screen, I would have to set the leftBarButtonItem manually again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then try using this:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
```

Comment: Nope. I want to SHOW the back button not hide it. I'm looking for something like "self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItemReplacesBackBarButtonItem = NO".

Comment: `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem` is always (null) for some reason (I guess because the leftBarButtonItem is set in IB). So that new code works only half as it does always hide the leftBarButtonItem now. I would need some conditional I guess which I could query on viewDidLoad to programmatically set the leftBarButtonItem to nil.

Comment: Yes,the best approach to do this to check whether any viewcontroller is being pushed on the stack.If yes,it means its being pushed,else its being presented(in this case backbutton will be (null)). Accordingly,write the code.

Comment: OK... So I am now using this code in my viewDidLoad and that works alright: `if(self.navigationController.topViewController == self && self.navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }`. Maybe someone can still point out a more elegant solution.

Comment: sir @Shantanu you are also great :)